# Kinect v2 with SDK v1.8

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I just ordered a Kinect v2. The Kinect Software Development Kit v2 requires Windows 8, so I'm wondering if I can use the SDK v1.8 with the Kinect v2, or if I'll need to upgrade to Windows 8. If SDK v1.8 is compatible, does anyone know if there are significant advantages to using v2?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK 1.8 is **not compatible** to Kinect v2. You have to use the SDK 2.0.

Or you could use [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2), the open source Kinect2 SDK. That works with Windows 7 (and Linux and Mac OS X). But it doesn't have advanced features like skeleton and face tracking that the Microsoft SDK has. Just the raw sensor data: depth, IR, RGB images, registered to each other or not.

Answer (score 0):

The  Windows 8 is  MINIMUM requirement to developing kit v2 .
you can not use the SDK v1.8 with the Kinect v2 .